# Loop driver.get URL (webdriver python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can i loop a URL infinitely in Python Selenium WebDriver? I have tried time.sleep driver.refresh() but it is not very efficient.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    import os
    import time

    chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://www.example.com/load")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An infinite loop in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623045/an-infinite-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
print "To quit the program, please kill the program or close browser"
while True:
    driver.get("http://www.bbc.com/")
```

This will help to solve your problem